# A specified Include path is not valid

Tags: c#, entity-framework, include, ef-code-first

I am getting an error when using .Include - `A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'myProject.DAL.Paint' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Color'.`

DAL

```
public DBSet<Palete> Paletes {get; set; }
public DbSet<Paint> Paints { get; set; }
```

(note: `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();`)

Model

```
public class Palete
{
  public virtual Paint Paint { get; set; }
}

public class Paint
{
    public string Color { get; set; }
}
```

`query = query.Include(pal => pal.Paint.Color);`

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Just so you know, the correct spelling is [palette](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/palette)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Color` is a string property - you shouldn't need an `Include` here since `Color` doesn't refer to a separate entity.

Given the update doing just

```
query = query.Include(pal => pal.Paint);
```

should work - if you are querying the `Pallete` entities.

Comment: The include reference is actually nested, I will provide a more verbose example.

Comment: Why is including only the color not going to work (Assuming that paint has multiple other fields)?

Comment: An `Include` query only works on full entities - if you want to limit your query to partial data you can further constrain the results by using a projection with `Select`

Comment: Oh, that is neat :) Thanks again!